# How to access Excel cells hosted on Sharepoint (Office 365) using Java client?

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, wsdl, java-api

I host my site in [asphostportal](http://asphostportal.com/) and I am trying to build a Java clinet that connects to Sharepoint (mysite.sharepoint.com) and grabs an excel file. I used the Excel services WSDL file, however the ExcelServices does not provide a Credential property to authenticate unlike its .Net counter part.

I am even trying to figure out the REST API for accessing the excel file. All i need is some why for my java clinet to use the API (either soap or rest) and grab specific cell data from the excel to my java web application.

I have been looking for a clean solution but for the life of me I couldn't find it ...

Any help is greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Since [Excel Services in SharePoint 2013/Online supports supports OData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163211.aspx), the following examples demonstrate how to retrieve table content:

- `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Documents/ciscoexpo.xlsx/OData/CiscoSalesTable` get all table data
- `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Documents/ciscoexpo.xlsx/OData/CiscoSalesTable?$filter=Sales ge 100` get specific rows

> Prerequisite: excel file have to be prepared as explained in `Prepare
>   excel data` section

Follow [Requesting Excel workbook data from SharePoint Server using OData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163211.aspx) for a more details.

### Prepare excel data

Assume the following excel file

[image]

that contains the following items in the workbook:

- table (how to [Create or delete an Excel table in a worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556413.aspx))
- chart

Before uploading file into SharePoint library, go to `File -> Browse View Options ->  choose Items in the Workbook` as demonstrated below. Then save file and upload it into SharePoint `Documents` library.

[image]

### How to read excel data via Excel Services 2010 REST API

I don't have any Java examples that demonstrates how to consume Excel Services, but you could consider the following example in C# as a starting point:

```
using System.Net;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Office
{
    public class ExcelClient : WebClient
    {

        public ExcelClient(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials)
        {
            BaseAddress = webUrl;
            Credentials =  credentials;
            Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }

        public string ReadTable(string libraryName, string fileName, string tableName,string formatType)
        {
            var endpointUrl = BaseAddress + string.Format("/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/{0}/{1}/OData/{2}", libraryName, fileName, tableName);
            return DownloadString(endpointUrl);
        }

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var credentials = GetCredentials(webUrl,username,password);
var client = new ExcelClient(webUrl, credentials);
var tableData = client.ReadTable("Documents","ciscoexpo.xlsx", "CiscoSalesTable");
```

where

```
private static SharePointOnlineCredentials GetCredentials(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
    return new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
}
```

**References**

[Excel Services REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556413.aspx)