# Modifying already existing excel file in the sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-online

What is the recommended method for modifying an existing Excel file stored in a SharePoint site without downloading it locally? Are there any specific APIs, such as the Microsoft Graph API or the SharePoint REST API, that can be used for this purpose? Can you provide an example of code that uses these APIs to modify an Excel file in place on a SharePoint site?
Can I do it with this:

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/Add(url='{file_name}', overwrite=true)
```

I know that `PUT` is the only method that I can use to update a file but I can't find the relevant API for modifying just one cell in the Excel file on the sharepoint site.

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141881/how-to-access-excel-cells-hosted-on-sharepoint-office-365-using-java-client?rq=1

Comment: working with Power Automate suits you ?

Comment: I don't mind the framework or the language as long as I can modify the excel cells in the sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Automate is one way to do it, you could use [Write to Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/excel#writetoexcel) action to begin with.

Or you have time, may consider exploring Excel graph API from this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0.